# Relocating functions during run time - gcc

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-construction, linker, lds

I'm working with 2 memories on my device, DDR and SRAM. The device is running a pre-OS code written in C and ARM.

I would like to conduct a DDR calibration, for that I need to copy a few functions to the SRAM, jump to it, run the calibration code, and go back to DDR when done.

In order to do so, I've modify my scatter file (.lds) so the relevant functions will be mapped to SRAM (instructions, data etc.).
After compiling the image, he is copied into the DDR and start running from there.

My problem is as follows:
How can I locate the starting address and size of these functions on DDR, so I'll be able to copy them to the SRAM and jump there?

Thanks you all in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are talking about `ARM` architecture:

1. compile the code with `__attribute__((always_inline));` on all related functions and compile with `-fpic -fPIC` read [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html) for more info.
2. disassembling it and put it as-is on SRAM, e.g at adress `0xd1001000`
3. reserve `{r4-r15}` on SRAM.
4. set `pc` to `0xd1001000` and `sp` properly to point the stack.
5. restore `{r4-r15}`
6. jump back to DDR.

You can look at [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html) for a good resource of how to use the right gcc flags.

---

here is a refernce from [uboot](http://git.denx.de/) - it doesn't jump back to the initial place:

```
/*
 * void relocate_code (addr_sp, gd, addr_moni)
 *
 * This "function" does not return, instead it continues in RAM
 * after relocating the monitor code.
 *
 */
    .globl  relocate_code
relocate_code:
    mov r4, r0  /* save addr_sp */
    mov r5, r1  /* save addr of gd */
    mov r6, r2  /* save addr of destination */

    /* Set up the stack                         */
stack_setup:
    mov sp, r4

    adr r0, _start
    cmp r0, r6
    moveq   r9, #0      /* no relocation. relocation offset(r9) = 0 */
    beq clear_bss       /* skip relocation */
    mov r1, r6          /* r1 <- scratch for copy_loop */
    ldr r3, _image_copy_end_ofs
    add r2, r0, r3      /* r2 <- source end address     */

copy_loop:
    ldmia   r0!, {r9-r10}       /* copy from source address [r0]    */
    stmia   r1!, {r9-r10}       /* copy to   target address [r1]    */
    cmp r0, r2          /* until source end address [r2]    */
    blo copy_loop

#ifndef CONFIG_SPL_BUILD
    /*
     * fix .rel.dyn relocations
     */
    ldr r0, _TEXT_BASE      /* r0 <- Text base */
    sub r9, r6, r0      /* r9 <- relocation offset */
    ldr r10, _dynsym_start_ofs  /* r10 <- sym table ofs */
    add r10, r10, r0        /* r10 <- sym table in FLASH */
    ldr r2, _rel_dyn_start_ofs  /* r2 <- rel dyn start ofs */
    add r2, r2, r0      /* r2 <- rel dyn start in FLASH */
    ldr r3, _rel_dyn_end_ofs    /* r3 <- rel dyn end ofs */
    add r3, r3, r0      /* r3 <- rel dyn end in FLASH */
fixloop:
    ldr r0, [r2]        /* r0 <- location to fix up, IN FLASH! */
    add r0, r0, r9      /* r0 <- location to fix up in RAM */
    ldr r1, [r2, #4]
    and r7, r1, #0xff
    cmp r7, #23         /* relative fixup? */
    beq fixrel
    cmp r7, #2          /* absolute fixup? */
    beq fixabs
    /* ignore unknown type of fixup */
    b   fixnext
fixabs:
    /* absolute fix: set location to (offset) symbol value */
    mov r1, r1, LSR #4      /* r1 <- symbol index in .dynsym */
    add r1, r10, r1     /* r1 <- address of symbol in table */
    ldr r1, [r1, #4]        /* r1 <- symbol value */
    add r1, r1, r9      /* r1 <- relocated sym addr */
    b   fixnext
fixrel:
    /* relative fix: increase location by offset */
    ldr r1, [r0]
    add r1, r1, r9
fixnext:
    str r1, [r0]
    add r2, r2, #8      /* each rel.dyn entry is 8 bytes */
    cmp r2, r3
    blo fixloop
    b   clear_bss
_rel_dyn_start_ofs:
    .word __rel_dyn_start - _start
_rel_dyn_end_ofs:
    .word __rel_dyn_end - _start
_dynsym_start_ofs:
    .word __dynsym_start - _start

#endif  /* #ifndef CONFIG_SPL_BUILD */

clear_bss:
#ifdef CONFIG_SPL_BUILD
    /* No relocation for SPL */
    ldr r0, =__bss_start
    ldr r1, =__bss_end__
#else
    ldr r0, _bss_start_ofs
    ldr r1, _bss_end_ofs
    mov r4, r6          /* reloc addr */
    add r0, r0, r4
    add r1, r1, r4
#endif
    mov r2, #0x00000000     /* clear                */

clbss_l:str r2, [r0]        /* clear loop...            */
    add r0, r0, #4
    cmp r0, r1
    bne clbss_l

/*
 * We are done. Do not return, instead branch to second part of board
 * initialization, now running from RAM.
 */
jump_2_ram:
/*
 * If I-cache is enabled invalidate it
 */
#ifndef CONFIG_SYS_ICACHE_OFF
    mcr p15, 0, r0, c7, c5, 0   @ invalidate icache
    mcr     p15, 0, r0, c7, c10, 4  @ DSB
    mcr     p15, 0, r0, c7, c5, 4   @ ISB
#endif
    ldr r0, _board_init_r_ofs
    adr r1, _start
    add lr, r0, r1
    add lr, lr, r9
    /* setup parameters for board_init_r */
    mov r0, r5      /* gd_t */
    mov r1, r6      /* dest_addr */
    /* jump to it ... */
    mov pc, lr

_board_init_r_ofs:
    .word board_init_r - _start
```